# Python returns 0 for all my divisions (even when using float())

Tags: python, division

I'm using Spyder (Python 2.7)

Any division that would return a value below 1 returns 0.

When I use float(5/10) it returns 0.0

When I use:
'%.11f'%a  after defining a = 10/20 it still returns 0.000000000..

I'm really new to Python, I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

How do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: It is. I will delete the post. Thank you for the quick help!

Comment: If you actually want to use `float`, you need to do it as `float(5)/10`.

Answer (score -1):

Very noob.

For this to work one must just import:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: actually float(5)/float(10) would also work